# Does asyncronous I/O consume threads?

Tags: scala, scalability, akka, reactive-programming

I'm trying to grok akka actors and determine their benefits. I understand that many actors can share the same thread thus gaining huge efficiencies - but in the context of a web application, the web container should do the same between requests correct?

So the benefit could come down to I/O - blocking I/O pauses the thread for no-one else to use.

Does asynchronous I/O consume a thread or not? When I get a future for some I/O result will a thread be used while that I/O is completed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Java Asynchronous I/O model is described [here](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/resources/AsynchronousIo.html) at an easy enough level to grasp. The basic idea is that there's an internal thread pool which retrieves completed I/O notifications from the kernel and then dispatch to other threads to perform the required actions on it.

So, in a sense, yes, it uses threads. And here's something else to consider: so does everything. Every piece of software out there requires that a process, at some point, check whether a piece of I/O has completed so that it can perform follow-up tasks on it (well, it could be fire-and-forget, but that's somewhat limited for practical sues). On nodejs, famous for its asynchronous I/O, that thread is called the "event loop" (though the overall model is very different).

The point here is that there is not a correspondence of one thread per I/O operation. Instead, there's a single internal thread pool that's responsible for receiving all asynchronous I/O completion events, and then taking whatever actions are required on their completion.

Perhaps a better question is: does asynchronous I/O in Java consume threads in proportion to the number of I/O requests being processed? No, it doesn't; it consumes a fixed number of threads. More useful question: when initiating an asynchronous I/O in Java, does that block the thread that initiated the I/O? No, it does not; it returns immediately. And relevant question to the topic: does asynchronous I/O in Java uses threads from the actor thread pool? No, it doesn't.

Next, to the future returned by asynchronous I/O. While the I/O does not complete, no thread will be used. However, there is a *thread pool* assigned to the completion of that future, and, when the I/O completes, one thread from that pool will be used to perform the actions that you associate with that future's completion. Once those actions are finished, the thread will be returned to that thread pool. That thread pool is probably not going to be the same as the thread pool used by the actors (though I suppose there might be a way to make it so).

Comment: I belive akka's `implict val exec = context.dispatcher` means that the IO results will be retrieved in the same thread pool. I thought about altering my question to be clearer about proportionality, but perhaps your answer is "No, it does not _consume_ threads, but it does _use_ threads". Marking as the answer since it's in-depth.

Comment: @Stephen There might be an implicit, but _Java_ doesn't use implicits, so it will ignore that. If you are using async i/o from some other library, then you'll have to check on its own documentation.

Comment: Awesome - completely forgot that Akka is a Java lib too ;). Presumably you could still use the `context.dispatcher` for `Future` executions though?

Comment: @Stephen Yes, but note that a Scala `Future` does _not_ make an I/O asynchronous! If you do something like `Future { blockingIO() }`, you'll get a thread blocked on I/O. You can use `Promise` to create a `Future` and combine that with the async call back, though.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR on the accepted answer: No, threads are not *consumed* by aysnchronous I/O, but threads are *used* to retrieve the I/O results from the kernel.

Also, from [Play Framework: async I/O without the thread pool and callback hell](http://engineering.linkedin.com/play/play-framework-async-io-without-thread-pool-and-callback-hell):

> On Evented servers, waiting for I/O is very cheap: idle requests have negligible cost, as they don’t hold up a thread.

Comment: Yes, this is correct - but it only applies to *non-blocking* I/O. You can't make blocking I/O into non-blocking I/O simply by sprinkling some Akka magic on it - it doesn't work like that. This is a well-known problem in the node.js community which has resulted in many libraries being rewritten to do asynchronous I/O. In the JVM world, there is, surprisingly, no equivalent to JDBC for asynchronous database access, although a handful of databases have async APIs that can be used from Java and Scala.

Comment: By the way *making blocking IO into non-blocking IO by sprinkling some magic on it* -- is what [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#monkey-patching) all about, in python world of course.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Thanks, interesting! I was thinking about using metaprogramming for this - but in a very different way. Another idea to look into!